# Average of a table column in python

Tags: python

Ok code created which outputs a table like this:

```
[['              ' '     Scarface ' '     Godfather' '        Avatar']
['Al Pachino    ' '             1' '             1' '            -1']
['Marlon Brando ' '            -1' '             1' '            -1']
['De Niro       ' '            -1' '             1' '            -1']
['Sigorny Weaver' '            -1' '            -1' '             1']]
```

How do I get the average of a table column by writing a function whose arguments are a table of integer numbers A and a positive integer number i. The function should return the average of non-negative entries of the column i of A.

I want to do this in the most simple readable code which later I can explain to kids.

Thanks Jemma

Comment: Have you tried something? Where is your code?

Comment: Could you provide a full example (using the data of your table) of what you want ?

Comment: What is a "table?" What you have here is a list of lists where each sublist contains a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get average with formula `<ONLY-POSITIVE-VALUES> / <ALL-INTEGER-COLUMS>`

```
data = [
    ['              ', '     Scarface ', '     Godfather', '        Avatar'],
    ['Al Pachino    ', '             1', '             1', '            -1'],
    ['Marlon Brando ', '            -1', '             1', '            -1'],
    ['De Niro       ', '            -1', '             1', '            -1'],
    ['Sigorny Weaver', '            -1', '            -1', '             1']
]

def compute_average(row):
    average = 0
    count   = 0
    for column in row:
        count += 1
        try:
            value = int(column)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        if value > 0:
            average += value

    return float(average) / count

for row in data[1:]:
    print compute_average(row)
```

If you need formula like `<ONLY-POSITIVE-VALUES> / <ALL-POSITIVE-VALUES-COLUMS>` just move the `count += 1` line from the top of `for` loop to the `if value > 0` statement.

The `try` / `except` part is only because Python raise error when you try to parse a non-integer string in integer, it allow you to fetch any data and just skip non-integer ones.